# Time reference and express attractivness of a fitting job role in cover letter?

Tags: grammar, expressions

I found a job ad of a job which is perfect for me.

I have the following sentences:

> After my studies and acquiring the IBM certificates I am now searching
>   for a position as an programmer.
>   The position at the xxx ideally for me combines the possibilities to
>   gain experience in the public sector consultancy and work at an
>   academic institution.

I think the construction of "ideally for me combines the possibilities" is wrong. I am not sure to switch the ideally with the for me and take ideal, also should I use possibility or possibliites?

**Second** I am not sure how to adress the time in this sense.
I did the IBM certifications at the end of my studies (mainly) and one took more time, so I had to spend 5 month afterwards on this single certification. I want to say that after my studies and after the time I needed to get these certificates I am now searching for a job (and of course this one fits).

Comment: So you got all the certificates (except one) before you finished your degree, and then you got one more after you finished your degree?

Comment: @miltonaut Well, no. That is not the important point. But the first three were pretty easy, so I get them very fast. Within 1-2- month at the end of my studies I had them. The last one took more time.

Comment: In my experience, potential employers usually don't care how long it takes you to finish something unless it took an unusually long time or there was an unexplained gap--for instance, 10 years to complete a 4-year degree. Unless you know the companies you're applying to will care, I wouldn't mention anything about how long it took you to get them--just that you have them. I'm not in the tech field, so this advice may not apply.

Answer (score 0):

I would say "The position at X seems ideal for me, as it combines the opportunities of gaining experience in a public-sector consultancy and working at an academic institution."

Notice the "a" before "public", the hyphenation of "public-sector", and verb form "working" to parallel "gaining"